# How to configure AWS SQS via CDK to receive messages from outside world?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have a normal monolith app running on Heroku. I would like to use an SQS queue to process some background jobs.

Monolith -> posts to SQS -> SQS holds event & calls -> Monolith -> Confirms processing and deletes event from SQS

I already have an S3 bucket I have configured via the AWS CDK, now I'm trying to figure out to configure an SQS queue which I can also call from the outside (via access_token/key authentication):

```js
// The user I used for S3 uploads
const uploadUser = new iam.User(this, "upload-user", {
  userName: "upload-user",
})

// ...Here is some other code to initialize S3 bucket
const bucket = ...
bucket.grantWrite(uploadUser)

// But when creating a queue this does not work
const queue = new sqs.Queue(this, 'linear-sync.fifo')
queue.grant(uploadUser) // errors
```

Trying to do this gives me an error:

```
Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IGrantable'
```

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Edit: I ended up abandoning the idea of using a SQS queue, I might come back to it later, but decided to go for redis, it's easier to set up with our current docker-based stack but I might revisit the idea later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the [`Queue.grant`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-sqs.Queue.html#grantgrantee-actions) method requires you to list which actions you want to grant access to. If you want to post messages to the queue, you would call [`Queue.grantSend`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-sqs.Queue.html#grantwbrsendwbrmessagesgrantee).

Now, the reason `User` may not be assignable to `IGrantable` is because you have mismatched versions of CDK installed. Are you using V1? Are all the CDK modules the same version? Make sure you're not using V1 and V2 together.

Comment: Ah sorry, I abandoned my plans to use SQS since it wasn't working for me, and also set up for local development would be painful for my non-tech team members. I do believe however you are right, I just installed the latest version of the SQS package and did not update the rest